# Why do I receive Non-exhaustive patterns in function compuneList

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I am trying to write a function called aplicaList which receives a number and list of functions [(a -> b)] , I want to return a list containing all the results [f(a)]

Function compuneList is a function which receives a function f and a list of other functions [(g)] and results a list of functions [f(g())].

```
compuneList :: (b -> c) -> [(a -> b)] -> [(a -> c)] 
compuneList f [] = []
compunelist f (ff : xs) = (f . ff : compuneList f xs)

aplicaList :: a -> [(a -> b)] -> [b]
aplicalist a [] = []
aplicaList a (f : xs) = (f(a) : aplicaList a xs)
```

The program compiles, but when I try to interpret aplicatList 9 [(+1), (+3)] I get:

**[10,12  Exception: Lab4.hs:59:1-48: Non-exhaustive patterns in function aplicaList**

and when I try aplicaList 9 (compuneList (+1) [sqrt, (^2), (/2)]) I get:

**Exception: Lab4.hs:54:1-21: Non-exhaustive patterns in function compuneList**

I do not know why in both cases. Thank you.

Comment: How are you executing these? Are you typing them into GHCi by any chance?

Comment: Your line `aplicalist a [] = []` should be `aplicaList a [] = []`.

Comment: Function names are case-sensitive, and you have a typo of `compunelist` for `compuneList`, which means you are defining two separate partial functions rather than a single total function. (Same for the second function, as pointed out by Simon Shine.)

Comment: There's no need for explicit recursion here anyway; `compuneList f = map (f .)` and `aplicaList a = map ($ a)`.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your warnings are two typos:

- `aplicalist a [] = []` should be `aplicaList a [] = []`.
- `compunelist f (ff : xs)` should be `compuneList f (ff : xs)`.

Be aware of big and small letters when you code.

---

If you run your code through HLint, it will suggest that you can eliminate a bunch of parentheses.

You can also reduce explicit recursion using `map`:

```hs
compuneList :: (b -> c) -> [a -> b] -> [a -> c]
compuneList f = map (f .)

aplicaList :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
aplicaList a = map (\f -> f a)
```

Comment: It was because the small and big letters, thank you

Comment: @AnduMîndrescu: If you turn on compiler warnings and linting in your editor, you will receive meaningful messages that will suggest this. For example, a giveaway is that the first definition after your type signatures is for something other than what's in your type signatures.